# Remove or push if an Array of values exists in another array of objects in ES6, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have and array of objects with the details of certain food:

```
let food = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Peas', comments: ''},
    {id: 2, name: 'Oranges', comments: ''},
    {id: 3, name: 'Bananas', comments: ''},
    {id: 4, name: 'Grapefruits', comments: ''},
    {id: 5, name: 'Apples', comments: ''}
];
```

A second array includes all the selected food IDs that the user can select in a multi-select dropdown:

```
let selectedFood = [1, 5];
```

and a third array is where I want to add/remove items based on the selectedFood IDs - right now it should include IDs `1` and `5`:

```
let newFood = [
   {id: 1, name: 'Peas'},
   {id: 5, name: 'Apples'}
]
```

If we select a new food, let's say, Bananas, then the `selectedFood` array should look like:

```
let selectedFood = [1, 5, 3];
```

... and the newFood array:

```
let newFood = [
   {id: 1, name: 'Peas'},
   {id: 5, name: 'Apples'},
   {id: 3, name: 'Bananas'}
]
```

If we want to remove an item, let's say `Peas` from the selected food it should remove it from both the `selectedFood` and `newFood` arrays:

```
let selectedFood = [5, 3];

let newFood = [
   {id: 5, name: 'Apples'},
   {id: 3, name: 'Bananas'}
]
```

Is there any quick and easy way of doing this? I know I can do `forEach` on `selectedFood` and find/filter on newFood then push/splice based on the result. However is there a simple ES6 way of achieving this?

**Update #1:**

One thing that I forgot to mention is, I want to keep the current array instead of creating a new one. The reason for that is, I might change/add some other values before removing/adding an item.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
let food = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Peas', comments: ''},
    {id: 2, name: 'Oranges', comments: ''},
    {id: 3, name: 'Bananas', comments: ''},
    {id: 4, name: 'Grapefruits', comments: ''},
    {id: 5, name: 'Apples', comments: ''}
];

let selectedFood = [1, 5, 3];

const result = food.filter(e => selectedFood.includes(e.id));

console.log(result);
```

If you need only `id` and `name` fields then at the end you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

I hope this helps!

Comment: The important part is that functions like `filter` and `map` always create new arrays. So there is no need to modify existing arrays.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually a pretty good approach and almost good for me. One thing that I forgot to mention is ideally I want to keep the current array instead of creating a new one. The reason for that is I might change/add some other values before removing/adding an item. I've updated the original question with this.